# 一单字动词，表示给食物过冷水，是哪个字？ / a single-character word meaning to submerge food in cold water

Tags: word-choice, topolect, character-identification

北京话里有个单字动词，表示给食物（比如刚煮熟的面条、蔬菜等）过冷水。华北其他地区可能也说。请问这是哪个字？以前经常听人说，现在记不清了。

There is a single-character verb in Beijingese Mandarin, meaning to submerge food (like boiled noodles, vegetables, etc.) in cold water. It is possibly used in other parts of Northern China as well. May I know which word is this? I used to hear it a lot but forgot what it exactly was.

Comment: `过水儿`.......................

Comment: @songyuanyao I'm looking for a verb of only one character.

Comment: I only know some verbs meaning to submerge food in _hot_ water. They are 汆、涮、焯.

Comment: I don't know, we say 过水 in 东北。

Comment: I only know in Beijing dialect, `过水儿` means submerge noodles in cold water, `锅儿挑` means don't `过水儿`, eat noodles while they are hot...

Comment: 广东这边是叫过冷河，北方怎么叫还真不知道= =

Comment: In Shanghainese we use 焯 (IPA [tsʰɔ]) or 汆 (IPA [tsʰø]).

Comment: @FanZheng I can't speak for Wu Chinese but at least in Northern China those two means to submerge in _hot_ water instead of cold water.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

拔（pronunciation only. Not sure how to write.）。
e.g. 面条放冷水里拔一下

焯是过热水。

Comment: Confirm with 现代汉语规范词典 / The Standard Dictionary of Contemporary Chinese Copyright © 2010, 2012 Oxford University Press and Foreign Language Teaching and Research Publishing, Co., Ltd. See 拔 (6)